# xmlpull ,can't parse tag event.there is only start and end of document

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have searched my problem, there is no result, so i'm here to ask you all friends.

This is the problem:

> when i parse xml, `xmlpull` always parse this two event eventType (`START_DOCUMENT`, `END_DOCUMENT`), so i can't parse any useful message in tag eventType.

This is my code:

```
public Map<String, String> parse(Reader reader) {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            // 
            XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(reader);
            // 
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            String name = null;
            String value = null;
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)) {
                    name = parser.getName();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    value = parser.getText();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    result.put(name, value);
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I debugged my code, this is the process: 
first, `eventType = START_DOCUMENT` -> then, `eventType = parser.next()`; -> `eventType = END_DOCUMENT`, so i can't read child node of root.

so, how to solve this problem. thank at first to you all.

Answer (score 0):

oh no, I find the problem, it's all because I use `bufferedReader.readLine()` to read it before i parse the xml....

so stupid...